# How do I play an animation through a button that is already set up to play music? (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, android-mediaplayer

As said in the title, I have already set up a button to play specific music, but then I also want it to activate an animation from an already existing imageview that would play along with it (for my case, sheet music for a piece of music) and then revert back to the original imageview if the button is repressed (stopping the music) or when the song is finished.

The code for the activity with the button is here:

```
package net.ZachApps.sheetmusicapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ElDoradoScore extends Activity {

Button btnElDorado;
ImageView imgscore;
MediaPlayer songElDorado;
int playing;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eldoradoscore);
        btnElDorado = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnElDorado);
        btnElDorado.setOnClickListener(bElDorado);
        songElDorado = new MediaPlayer();
        songElDorado = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eldoradoscore);
        playing = 0;
    }
    Button.OnClickListener bElDorado = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(playing){
        case 0:
            songElDorado.start();
            playing=1;
            btnElDorado.setText("Stop El Dorado Song");

            break;
        case 1:
            songElDorado.stop();
            playing = 0;
            btnElDorado.setText("Start El Dorado Song");

            break;
        }

        }

    };
}
```

I have the animation saved as res/anim/score.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop1" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop2" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop3" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop4" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop5" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop6" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop7" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop8" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop9" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop10" android:duration="2000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/eldoradop11" android:duration="2000" />
</animation-list>
```

I have tried to look for a way to activate the animation from the button (with the cases), but I haven't found helpful information when I have searched. What should I do from here?
I know there is another way to set it up but I want to know if it is possible from this point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Add another member variable:

```
AnimationDrawable animation;
```

Add in the `onCreate` method:

```
imgscore = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgscore); // assuming that's the name
imgscore.setBackgroundResource(
    R.drawable.your_animation_resource); // I don't know the resource name
animation = (AnimationDrawable)imgscore.getBackground();
```

Add under `case 0` in your `OnClickListener`'s switch statement:

```
animation.start();
```

And under `case 1`:

```
animation.stop();
```

Depending on the behavior you desire, you may also want to set the visibility of the `ImageView` in your `OnClickListener`.

Edit:
As a side note, you should be sure to call `release` on the `MediaPlayer` at an appropriate time (at the very least, in `onDestroy`), and depending on your intentions, you may need a little more sophisticated treatment to produce the desired behavior.